# Adobe Illustrator Round Merged Shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator

So I'm trying to make a flat earth for a video.
[image]

But the merged shape's corners wont go any roundier (Please replace that with a better word!)

I am trying to make something like this[image]

Comment: How are you rounding the shape corners in the first place?

Comment: @JohnB, Hi, it looks like he is using the  Rounded Rectangle Tool but he's been using it wrong :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Live Corners** to really quickly make shapes like these (version CC 2014 or newer). Use the Direct Selection or Lasso tools to isolate the corners you'd like to round then with the Direct Selection tool click and drag the Corner widget until the edge turns red.

[image: Live Corners demonstration]

More information on Live Corners:

- [Illustrator Help /Live Rectangles and Rounded Rectangles](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/live-shapes.html)
- [Live Corners](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/illustrator-live-corners.html)
- [How to work with Live Corners in Illustrator](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/live-corners-in-illustrator.html)

Comment: Hey there, good answer, totally forgot about this, rarely using it :) Thanks for bringing it up but...doesn't this work only in CC ?

Comment: @Alin good point, this was introduced in CC 2014 (though SmashDev is using CC 2015). I'll make a note of that in my answer

Comment: Didn't look at what he's using :D Just thought there should be a mention there for people who don't know and are looking for it :)

Answer (score 2):

I am gonna give you another way of doing this cause I find it easier to calculate rather than using lines with strokes:

- Select the **Rounded Rectangle Tool** you already used, click anywhere on the artboard, give it a **Width** and a **Height** and set the **Corner Radius** to **890 px** , this way, when you click and drag to create new ones, it will (if the height of the object is less than 1780px) always give the desired half-circle margin.
- Go ahead and make another one and place it under it.
- Create a simple rectangle between them with the desired width of the link between the two and the height equivalent to the gap between them
- Take the **Circle** tool and draw two circles the exact same height as the rectangle .
- Place each circle with the top-middle anchor point over the rectangle's top-left and top-right anchor points.
- Select the two circles and the rectangle and go to **Pathfinder** > **Minus Front**.
- Select all the remaining objects and go **Pathfinder** > **Unite**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to make those shapes, you are going about it all wrong. You see how the rounded-rectangle shapes in the gif have rounded-edges of different sizes? You can't do that in Illustrator using the Round-Corners effect alone. It will try to force the same size corner on all different sized corners. Like this:

[image]

Here's how you do it right:

1. Draw a line

[image]

2. Increase the stroke

[image]

3. In the Stroke window, select the middle icon next to "Cap"

[image]

[image]

4. Duplicate your line. Change it's shape by changing the line thickness and/or shortening or lengthening the line itself.

[image]

5. With your two lines selected go to Object >> Expand (make sure "stroke" is checked), hit ok. Your two lines should now be two rounded shapes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

6. Add a rectangle that connects your two shapes

[image]

7. With all three shapes selected, go to the Pathfinder window, and select the "Unite" button (first icon on the left, under "Shape"). Should look like the icon below. Now you have a single shape. Almost there.

[image]

[image]

8. Draw another line with a rounded stroke. The distance between your first two shapes is how thick you want the stroke to be. Place the rounded corner of this line just over the connecting part.

[image]
[image]

9. Duplicate the line. and move it to the other side of the connecting shape.

[image]

10. Select the two lines and expand them. (object >> expand)
11. Select all your shapes now

[image]

12: Go to the Pathfinder window and now use "Minus Front" (this should be the second icon under the words "Modes")

[image]

13: DONE! Ooh that's a nice shape you got there.

[image]

14: Continue doing this with different shape combinations and stroke thicknesses to build the earth.  Cheers!

[image]

Comment: =)) This is the biggest answer I have ever seen...you could've probably narrow it down to less than a third ...but anyways, +1 for this illustration and for actually giving an ok answer :)